# Throttle movement in the cockpit

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
   void HandleMouse()
    {

   if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {

   if(isTouching)
    {

   HandleDragging();

    }
    }

   else
    {
   isTouching = false;
   ResetKnob();
        }
    }

    void HandleTouches()
    {

    }

 protected virtual void HandleDragging()
    {
  //Get the target position for the knob
    Vector2 wantedPosition = Vector2.zero;
    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(bounds, Input.mousePosition, null, out wantedPosition);
    knob.anchoredPosition = Vector2.Lerp(knob.anchoredPosition, wantedPosition, Time.deltaTime * dragSpeed);

    //Find the normalized Delta for the Knob
     float xDelta = knob.anchoredPosition.x / (bounds.rect.width * 0.5f);
     float yDelta = knob.anchoredPosition.y / (bounds.rect.height * 0.5f);
     finalDelta = new Vector2(xDelta, yDelta);
     finalDelta = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(finalDelta, 1f);


    }

    void ResetKnob()
    {
    knob.anchoredPosition = Vector2.Lerp(knob.anchoredPosition, Vector2.zero, Time.deltaTime * resetSpeed);

    finalDelta = Vector2.zero;
    }
```

I am trying to move a throttle up and down in the 3d space .I am using a 3d throttle object in side the cockpit to move up and down using mouse point i tried for moving the 2d sprite using above code it works fine but not working  for moving a 3d throttle object.
spri

Comment: Sorry what? I absolutely don't get what you are talking about. Could you post your code and explain exactly what you expect and what is not behaving as you expect.

Comment: translate the throttle in vertical direction and convert that value between 0 to 1 to apply that value for flight movement

Comment: What are the `anchoredPosition` for the throttle at 0% and 100% ? From your code it seems like it's always lerping towards `Vector2.zero`.

Comment: throttle movement in 3d space in y axis using mouse i tried the above code for 2d movement for the sprite i tried for 3d it is not working i want to convert above code for the 3d space

Comment: Please answer my question. Repeating yourself doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

> Mathf.Lerp(inputvalue, -10f, 10f);

I think your error is you are trying to interpolate your input to 10, when the Lerp function can only interpolate [0,1], [Mathf.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html)

You need to call it as `Mathf.Lerp(-10, 10, inputValue);`
Once you get the interpolation value just add that to the translation

```
var value = Mathf.Lerp(-10, 10, inputValue);
transform.position += Vector3.forward * value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out how far your throttle is:

```cs
Vector2 throttleDownPosition = Vector2.zero;     // Or whatever it is. I can't tell from your code.
Vector2 throttleUpPosition = new Vector2(0f,1f); // Or whatever it is. I can't tell from your code.
Vector2 throttleCurrentPosition = knob.anchoredPosition;

// Calculate ratio between current throttle / full throttle
float throttlePercentage = 
        Vector2.Distance(throttleCurrentPosition, throttleDownPosition) 
        / Vector2.Distance(throttleUpPosition, throttleDownPosition);
```

Then, using what position and rotation your 3D throttle object should be when throttle is at 0%:

- `Vector3 startPosition`
- `Quaternion startRotation`

as well as the position and rotation your 3D throttle object should be when throttle is at 100%:

- `Vector3 endPosition`
- `Quaternion endRotation`

you can use `Vector3.Lerp` and `Quaternion.Lerp` to find the appropriate position and rotation for the current throttle setting:

```cs
Vector3 lerpedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, throttlePercentage);
Quaternion lerpedRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startRotation, endRotation, throttlePercentage);

throttleObject.transform.position = lerpedPosition;
throttleObject.transform.rotation = lerpedRotation
```

Comment: how to use point to move throttle up and down using above code

Comment: use mouse point to move throttle up and down using above code

Comment: @robertmathew Your question said you already had an `inputValue`. What happened to that?

Comment: @robertmathew I edited my answer and did my best to use your throttle code, but there are some constants that are unclear in the code that you shared. Hopefully this helps.